Kalman Filter with diffusing "colored noise"
I am modeling a version of Kalman Filter with "colored measurement noise" that is diffusing.
Basically the measurement noise $v_k$ in the wikipedia convention diffuses. It doesn't follow $v_k \sim N(0,R)$, rather it follows $v_k = v_{k-1} + \zeta$ where  $\zeta \sim N(0,R)$. My $R$ is diagonal if it helps. In my case $F = I$ too ($F$ is the state-transition matrix).
One solution is to augment the state. i.e. model $v_k$ as a part of  the state. But I'd rather not do that for computational reason, because I have a lot of of observations. I found another solution mentioned in A. E. Bryson, Jr. & 1. J. Henrikson - Technical Report - ESTIMATION USING SAMPLED DATA CONTAINING SEQUENTIALtY CORRELATED NOISE.
Page 13 of the PDF (page 10 of the original paper) is the core part. Here they model
$v_k = \Psi_i v_{k-1} + \zeta$, construct $H_{i-1}^r = H_i F_{i-1} - \Psi H_{i-1}$ (I translate to wikipedia convention here) and operate on  $H_{i-1}^r$.
My question is, if $F_i = I$ or $\Psi = 1$ as in my case, $H_{i-1}^r =0$.  Or even if $H_i$ and $H_{i-1}$ are in different dimensions, this would stop working?  Did I understand this correctly? Or is there a more appropriate solution for me that doesn't introduce new states?

Why would your state transition matrix be an identity? That would mean that the true state is never changing and you are attempting to filter out sequentially correlated noise, in which it would probably just be easier to filter each state using an AR model.

@Baddioes thanks for the reply but we still have process noise ($Q$ matrix), so my true states still change (you can imagine like a random walk).  As in $x_k = x_{k-1} + w_k$ where $w_k \sim N(0,Q)$.

If the state transition matrix is an identity matrix, the true state won't experience a random walk, but the predicted state would due to the process noise. I would have to give this more thought, but it seems that the measurements could be denoised via an AR model, and then the standard Kalman equations would apply. Like I said though, I'd have to give this more thought.

@Baddioes I don't think that's right. State transition matrix is an "ideal, no noise" transition of true states. The process noise is exactly to account for the fact that state transition matrix will not be perfect, there will be perturbation.  States will still change.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Underlying_dynamic_system_model

Sorry, wrote that late at night and looking back I don't know why I was thinking that. Probably mixed up process and measurement noise. In the case that $F=I$ and $\psi=1$, $H^{r}{i}$ would seem to me to be 0 because the difference in state ($\zeta{i-1} = z_{i}-\psi z_{i-1}$) would only be dependent on the measurement noise plus the measured process noise that is causing the random walk.

@TaylorFang, Please write the name of the papers and not URL links. Names are always searchable. URL's will change one day.

@Royi good point, thanks
